# CakePHP HABTM recursive issue

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

To explain the issue I'm having, I'll use an example. Let's say that I'm building a system where students can sign up for an afterschool class, but an administrator has to approve the sign-up in order for it to be valid. So I have these models:

- Calendar (belongs to "Teacher", hasAndBelongsToMany "Student")
- Student (hasAndBelongsToMany "Calendar")
- Teacher (hasMany "Calendar")

Now let's say I want to see a list of all of the unapproved sign-ups that are for ninth-graders. I want the list to include the calendar date, the student's name, and the teacher's name. I would do something like this:

```
$this->request->data = $this->Student->CalendarsStudent->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'CalendarsStudent.is_approved' => null,
        'Student.grade' => 9
    )
));
```

The problem with the above code is that the returned array is missing the teacher's name:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CalendarsStudent] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1274
                    [calendar_id] => 200
                    [student_id] => 872
                    [is_approved] => 
                )

            [Calendar] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 200
                    [date] => 2012-12-17
                    [teacher_id] => 1
                    [total_slots] => 15
                )

            [Student] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 872
                    [teacher_id] => 1
                    [first_name] => Billy
                    [last_name] => Smith
                    [grade] => 9
                )

        )

)
```

If I add `'recursive' => 2` to the `find` parameters, I get way too much information. `$this->request->data[0]['Calendar']` will have `[Teacher]`, which is what I want, but it will also have `[Student]`, which I don't want. Also, `$this->request->data[0]['Student']` will have subarrays that I don't want. It seems like `Containable` would fix this, but I can't get that to work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CakePHP's [[Containable Behavior]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).  It's amazing - easy to use and will return whatever you want it to.

**Side note:** If you're using "recursive" as anything other than -1 for ANYTHING, it should be a red flag.  Containable is the absolute way to go as it lets you specify easily and exactly what data you want returned. Recursive will often cause memory issues and or other badness.

**Best practice IMO:**  set `$recursive = -1;` in your AppModel.php and never set it to anything else...ever.

Comment: I find it very useful in many occasions and by default it is not set to -1 so it might not be so bad...
If i want to retrieve less data, then is when I set it to -1 or I make use of containable as you said.

Comment: @Dave I appreciate your answer, but, as I said, I tried `Containable` and couldn't get that to work either. I had this in the `find` parameters: `'contain' => array('CalendarsStudent', 'Calendar' => array('Teacher'), 'Student')`. It had absolutely no effect on the array returned, regardless of whether or not I had `recursive` in there.

Comment: @Nick - recursive must be set to -1 when using Containable.  If you cannot get Containable to work, post that as your question "how to get containable to work" or something, but - in this case, Containable IS the way to go.

Comment: @Steve - talk to experienced CakePHP developers, and I would guess you'll get a 99% "don't use recursive" agreement.  I believe they're even planning on removing the whole "recursive" idea in CakePHP3. Containable is SO much better in SO many ways and once you understand it, it's VERY simple.

Comment: @Dave I will take it into account.

Comment: @Dave I will try posting another question specifically about `Containable`. If it ends up working, I'll mark your answer as the correct one. Thanks for your help!

Comment: OMG, Containable Behavior just CHANGED MY LIFE! I wish I could upvote 100 times!

Comment: @Zach - I think I had that same moment a few years ago.  I understand completely.  Glad to pass along the help :)